# How do I determine the weight function for a regular Strum-Liouville problem given a set of boundary conditions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am given an eigenvalue problem of the form: $$\frac{d}{dx}[p(x)\frac{d\phi}{dx}]+q(x)\phi+\lambda\sigma(x)\phi=0$$
with boundary conditions:$$\phi(1)=0$$ $$\phi(2)-2\phi'(2)=0$$
In this case $\sigma$ is the weight function. I tried testing the conditions and I found that the operator L is "self-adjoint" with respect to the conditions. From what I understand, this means that $$(\lambda_m-\lambda_n)\int{\phi_n\phi_m\sigma(x)=0}$$ for $n\neq m$. I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1):

What you're saying is correct, but what's the question?

Comment: This is a comment - not an answer.

Comment: I know. My score is too low to comment... But given that the question is not one, I took license.

Comment: I think I am asked to explicitly write out the function $\sigma(x)$. It is question 5.5.2 in Haberman's pde textbook.

Comment: @OskarLimka Ahh - I see sorry about that.  I feel compelled to upvote now! :)

Comment: Thanks! (I've earned 10 more points somewhere else in the meantime :-) But I still feel there's something missing... do you mean find a possible expression for $\sigma$ that will make the operator $\phi\mapsto [p\phi']'+q\phi$ be self-adjoint with respect to scalar product $\langle\phi,\psi\rangle=\int_1^2 \phi\psi\sigma$?